# JPQL - how to select all entities not referred to by any row from other entity set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have entity `Parent` and `Child` with unilateral relation `Child` `n -> 1` `Parent`. In other words `Parent` does not know about its children.

How to write an `JPQL` query which would select all instances of `Parent` which are not referred to by a particular subset of `Child` which meet certain predicate?

Example:
`select all parents which are not referred to by children who are younger than 8 years`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the parent/child relationship, e.g.:

```
SELECT c, p.name FROM Country c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.capital p
```

If the nulls are a problem, you can get rid of them by adding something like:

```
... WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL
```

For further detailed explanation, see this guide: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_

If the parent does not know about the children, then you can achieve similar results by using a subquery to filter parent, e.g.:

```
SELECT e.parent_id
    FROM ParentEntity e
    WHERE e.parent_id NOT IN (
    SELECT c.parent_id FROM ChildEntity c) ...
```